# The scope of an object declared inside a function

Tags: c++, oop, object

I'm moving from java to c++ and and as I learn how things are done in C++, I sometimes get confused. I read online that if an object is created inside of a function it only exist inside the function unless it's declared using new. So I wrote the following code to test it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Student{
private:
    int ID;
    int score;
public:
    void setID(int num);
    int getID();
    void setScore(int num);
    int getScore();
};
void Student::setID(int num)
{
    ID = num;
}

int Student::getID()
{
    return ID;
}
void Student::setScore(int num)
{
    score = num;
}

int Student::getScore()
{
    return score;
}

class Creator
{
public:
    static int nextID;
    Student getObject();
};
int Creator::nextID = 0;
Student Creator::getObject()
{
    Creator::nextID++;
    Student temp;
    temp.setID(Creator::nextID);
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    Creator maker;
    Student pupil[4];

    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof(pupil)/sizeof(pupil[0])); i++)
    {
        pupil[i] = maker.getObject();
    }

    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof(pupil)/sizeof(pupil[0])); i++)
    {
        cout<< "Sudent ID: "<<pupil[i].getID()<<endl;
    }    

    int mark = 70;
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof(pupil)/sizeof(pupil[0])); i++)
    {
        pupil[i].setScore(mark);
        mark += 10;
    }

    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof(pupil)/sizeof(pupil[0])); i++)
    {
        cout<< "Sudent ID: "<<pupil[i].getID()<<" has score of: "<<pupil[i].getScore()<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program works as expected and that is what is confusing me. According to what I read the object created inside of `Student Creator::getObject()` should not exist outside of it. It's destroyed as the function returns. Yet, I'm returning the object that was created inside of `Student Creator::getObject()` and storing it in the pupil array, outside of `Student Creator::getObject()`.

Since it works, does it mean that the object was created on the heap? From what I read, if the object is created inside of a function and the new keyword wasn't used the object is created in the stack and destroyed as the function exits.

Comment: *"I read online that if an object is created inside of a function it only exist inside the function unless it's declared as an object."* How can an object created not be an object?

Comment: sorry, meant unless it's declared using the new keyword

Comment: How come I can do `int f() {int i = 7; return i;}  void f2() {int x = f(); System.out.println(x);}` in Java and it prints 7? Isn't `i` destroyed as the function returns?

Comment: Please don't confuse scope with lifetime, they are two different things.

Comment: @immibis fundamental types in Java are on the heap and can therefore be returned as values. I think Integer behaves like an int and is an Object so is created on the heap and reference-counted.

Comment: @stellarpower I never said anything about Integer, and also Integer isn't a primitive ("fundamental") type in Java.

Comment: @immibis That's what I'm saying. AFAIK the int is destroyed but like in C++ it is copied by value (unless optimised) out of the function into x and printed. However, if you had used the Integer class, things would be different and as you say, the Integer would have been cleaned-up by the garbage collector, because it is an object and so on the heap (I think)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding this function:

```
Student Creator::getObject()
{
    Creator::nextID++;
    Student temp;
    temp.setID(Creator::nextID);
    return temp;
}
```

What this is actually doing is creating a **COPY** of the returned value, using the class' copy constructor. The `temp` variable is is indeed removed off of the stack.

What you *can't* do, is this:

```
Student& Creator::getObject()
{
    Creator::nextID++;
    Student temp;
    temp.setID(Creator::nextID);
    return temp; // <- trying to return a reference transient memory
}
```

Comment: The second function should return `Student *`

Comment: Of course you can't do that, the compiler won't let you. The more interesting thing you can't do is having the second function return a `Student*`.

Comment: Edited the answer to be more relevant.

Answer (score 1):

> Since it works, does it mean that the object was created on the heap?

No. Nothing is dynamically allocated automatically (*on the heap*) unless you call `new Student()`

> From what I read, if the object is created inside of a function and the new keyword wasn't used the object is created in the stack and destroyed as the function exits.

That's fundamentally true, though you can return a *copy* of that object as your function's return value, and let the compiler to decide for [return value optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization).

Comment: Is the correct syntax to create an object on the heap new Student() or new Student? I came across code where the parentheses weren't included.

Comment: @WhatIf The correct method to create a `Student` instance on _the heap_ (it's actually called dynamic storage allocation, c++ doesn't have a notion of _heap_) is `new Student()`, yes.

Comment: What is the use of new Student? Does it also create an object?

Comment: @WhatIf Yes, it creates an object, but it's not recommended you use `new` directly yourself. Rather use smart pointers or containers.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your signature for getObject

```
Student Creator::getObject()
```

getObject returns a copy of whatever you return. It is true that `temp` will be destructed once your function exits but you are not returning the reference to temp, you are returning the value of temp.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, AFAIK all objects are created on the heap and Java reference-counts the objects for you. In C++, if you instantiate an object, then you are correct, it is created on the stack, unless you, or a function you call, use new. So:

Student s; // On stack

Student *sp = new Student; //On heap

Student &sr = *new Student; //On heap

In C++, all objects on the stack are destroyed when they go out of scope, so your object temp IS destroyed. In the code above, the objects pointed to/referenced by sp and sr remain when sp and sr themselves go out of scope. What happens is that a shallow copy (by default) is made of temp, and that is what is returned, after which temp itself is cleaned up. This is different from Java, where you are returning a reference. Actually, C++ is calling the copy-constructor to make a copy of temp, and by writing your own copy-ctor for Student, if your class held pointers or referencss, you cou.d make copies of these objects rather than just copying the pointer/reference, which is what happens with the default shallow copy.

Answer (score 0):

`temp` is created as a local variable, so its scope is indeed bound to the function. `temp` bites the big one at `getObject`'s end.

But `getObject` returns a `Student`, not a reference or pointer to a `Student`. At this point all sorts of cool things can happen at the whim of the compiler. `temp` could be copied, but since `temp` will never be used again in `getObject` it also could be moved. In some circumstances `temp` could be elided. The compiler will do whatever it deems the best option.

The best part is you probably won't even care.